# Visual Studio 2012 crashes after opening

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crash, internet-explorer-11

A few days ago I opened VS2012 just like I do every day and after getting the page where you select the project to open, VS2012 crashed. Restarting the computer, getting all latest Windows updates and playing with registry values did not help at all. See below for answer on how to fix this issue.

Comment: I tried many things, even re-installed VS2012 without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the problem is Internet Explorer 11. It turns out that installing IE11 is what caused VS2012 to crash and be useless. This will fix the issue:

You need to re-register ieproxy.dll - after this VS2012 started to work again.

32 bit systems:

```
regsvr ieproxy.dll
```

64 bit systems:

```
regsvr32 ieproxy.dll
```

Comment: Glad this worked out.  Curious though did you try repairing (not re-installing) before you manually `regsvr` the DLL?

Comment: Yes, I tried repairing before re-installing but that did not help.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  I wonder if it was a problem with IE's install then.  VS repair is really good about fixing issues like this.  So if it didn't work my next thought would be to look at IE.

Comment: I have to run this everytime I start VS2012. Is there a more permanent solution?

Comment: @usr4896260 Not sure what to tell you, I stopped using VS2012 a while ago. The problem at the time seemed to be related to IE install, maybe try reinstalling IE and make sure it works. Also, try updating to a newer version of VS, not reason to be using VS 2012 today.

Answer (score 0):

This worked like a charm for me:

1. FIRSTLY: To minimize the potential loss of your personal environment, you should consider creating a backup of your environment using the Export Settings wizard, and the Import Settings wizard to restore the settings if and when needed.
2. Delete the contents from the following folders:

   C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
      C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
      C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
3. Go to the Visual Studio IDE folder in command prompt and Run the following command:
   `.\devenv.exe /resetuserdata` from the Visual Studio IDE folder.

   *Typical location of Visual Studio IDE folder for 64 bit:* C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

   *Typical location of Visual Studio IDE folder for 32 bit:* C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

**Reference**: Microsoft's article- [If you have problems with TFS or Visual Studio flush the user cache … or not?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/)